# Like button "like" count is different if user is logged in or not

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I'm currently working on a site that has 14k likes when I'm logged in to facebook. But this number drops to 9.2k when I'm not logged into facebook.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: It may have to do with the public visibility of people's 'likes'. If not, I'd love to know this too.

Comment: Yes, I too was thinking it may have something to do with the current user having an access token or not.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post: http://faso.com/fineartviews/21028/facebook-like-button-count-inaccuracies. It may be that the inflated number being reported is the total engagement count for this page (Likes and Shares) where are you are looking for the Fan Count (how many people explicitly hit the like button).